# How do I add a pause, specifically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, text, pause

I really want to find a way to add a ***simple*** pause in JS, I know this is a duplicate question, but I cannot find a good answer! Please see my example in code below.

```
Console.log ('hello world!')
//here is where I want to insert a pause!
Console.log ('how are you?')
```

This way, the two lines of text will have about a three second pause (or however long) in-between.

Comment: setTimeout or async/await

Comment: Is it a timed pause or an indefinite pause? Please clarify?

Comment: Could you show me some quick code, just to show me how you would use them in Console.log ?

Comment: Do you literally want to freeze execution of JS and all that depends on it? I mean you say ***legitimate***,  which seems to suggest that the solutions you found are not legit. Why are they not legit?

Comment: `console.log('hello world!'); setTimeout(()=>console.log('how are you?'),3000);`  ya.. you seem to be implying that this does not seem legitimate to you.  that's kind of an opinion on how you think the language should be designed to suit a convenience, but unfortunately such a convenience would contradict the way execution flow would work.

Comment: Ok, I have to admit, I am a beginner, and I haven't found other answers to be completely useful.....I am sure they are legit, but I'm not a complete pro.....

Comment: There's a reason why a simple "pause" doesn't exist, at least in browsers. Blocking the main execution thread also freezes the web page. Is this being executed in a browser?

Comment: No, slappy, just in a JS running system app... Not for a website.

Comment: If it's a node app you can use Atomics.wait, (or I guess workers now too)

Comment: User120242, I entered the code you gave me, it worked..... Thank you! Just like I wanted!